# Javascript Opacity Change

Tags: javascript, html, random, opacity

Okay, I've made some changes, fixed some problems, but now it doesn't go though all the letters, some of the letters are made visible, and then the script stops. Also, how would I make the letters fade in? I thought I had it to, but the script doesn't pause for some reason, and you can't see the fade.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

        //alert("Script Loaded");

        var $TotalLetters = 16,
        $SwappedLets = 0,
        $L1 = false,
        $L2 = false,
        $L3 = false,
        $L4 = false,
        $L5 = false,
        $L6 = false,
        $L7 = false,
        $L8 = false,
        $L9 = false,
        $L10 = false,
        $L11 = false,
        $L12 = false,
        $L13 = false,
        $L14 = false,
        $L15 = false,
        $L16 = false,
        $RanNum = 0,
        $Holderval = 0;

        window.onload = function DOL() {
            DoOnLoad()
        }

        function DoOnLoad() { 
            //alert("DoOnLoad");
            /* Change the opacity of every letter randomly,
            CAN CHANGE IN SMALL TAG */

            if ($SwappedLets <= $TotalLetters + 1) {
                $RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*17); 
                //alert(window["$L" + $RanNum]);
                 if (window["$L" + $RanNum] == false) {
                    window["$L" + $RanNum] = true;
                    OPIncre($RanNum);
                }
            }

        } 

        function OPIncre(RN) {
            if (document.getElementById("tL" + RN).style.opacity <= 1) {
                document.getElementById("tL" + RN).style.opacity = $Holderval + 0.001;
                $Holderval = $Holderval + 0.001;
                window.setTimeout(OPIncre(RN),600);
            }
            else {
                $SwappedLets = $SwappedLets + 1;
                $Holderval = 0;
                window.setTimeout(DoOnLoad,500);    
            }
        } 

    </script>
```

----OLD:

I'm new at Javascript, and I'm having trouble getting the script to change html element's opacity randomly. The opacity of the elements by default is set to 0 in css. I've tried looking around and have yet to find a solution. I'm not getting any error's in Firefox's Javascript error console. Is there anything that is obviously wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        /*alert("Script Loaded");*/
        var $TotalLetters = 16,
        $SwappedLets = 0,
        $L1 = false,
        $L2 = false,
        $L3 = false,
        $L4 = false,
        $L5 = false,
        $L6 = false,
        $L7 = false,
        $L8 = false,
        $L9 = false,
        $L10 = false,
        $L11 = false,
        $L12 = false,
        $L13 = false,
        $L14 = false,
        $L15 = false,
        $L16 = false,
        $RanNum = 0;

        window.onload = function DOL() {
            DoOnLoad()
        }

        function DoOnLoad() {
            /*alert("DoOnLoad");*/
            /* Change the opacity of every letter randomly,
            CAN CHANGE IN SMALL TAG */

            if ($SwappedLets <= $TotalLetters + 1) {
                $RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*17);
                /*alert(window["$L" + $RanNum]);*/
                if (window["$L" + $RanNum] == false) {
                    window["$L" + $RanNum] = true;
                    OPIncre($RanNum);
                }
            }

        }

        function OPIncre(RN) {
            while (document.getElementById("tL" + RN).style.Opacity <= 1) {
                document.getElementById("tL" + RN).style.Opacity = document.getElementById("tL" + RN).style.Opacity + 0.1;
            }
            $SwappedLets = $SwappedLets + 1;
            window.setTimeout(DoOnLoad,500);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Wow. Instead of all this list of boolean values, consider using an array, your code will be much cleaner.

Comment: I would have used an array, but I'm still learning how to do those in Javascript.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. Don't use `Opacity`.

Comment: By the way, what is the function supposed to do? All I see is that it sets the random element's opacity to 1. So why not write simply `(element).style.opacity = 1` instead of using a loop?

Comment: I would like them to fade in, instead of just going straight to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of elements "tL" are, but assuming that they are of type `<p>` the following script should do the trick:

```
var $elements;
window.onload = function DOL() {
    // Get all elements
    $elements = $("p[id^='tL']");

    // Loop through all of them
    $elements.each(function(i, e) {
        e.style.opacity = Math.random() + 0.17;
    });
}
```

Note that I'm using jQuery here. Since you are using the dollor notation for variables, I assume you are using it too.

Comment: Variables in Javascript can contain dollar signs even without jQuery. It's just that some people like them that way.

Comment: I know, that's why I said that I only assumed.

Comment: Mr Lister was right in his assumption. I like using the dollar notation to make variables easier to spot. Thanks a lot though for your contribution! I'm not fully understanding what the difference between jQuery and Javascript is, do you mind explaining at all?

Comment: jQuery is a library that both simplifies writing of JavaScript functions, and makes them compatible with different/older browsers. You get more done with less code (verbose), and they have a great API. Plus, there's a bunch of questions about it here, so you will probably find solutions to all your problems.